# Remove duplicates from JSONArray java

Tags: java, arrays, json

I have a JSONArray with the collection of json objects. I want to remove duplicates from the list. Question seems to be simple. But the code in other Stack overflow answers seems to be large.

Someone provide me any solutions to handle this problem and make the code slimmer.

```
JSONArray jsonElement1 = new JSONArray("[{\"_index\":\"sales_csv\",\"_source\":{\"Order Date\":\"2016-01-28T18:37:00.000Z\"},\"sort\":[1576653361740],\"_score\":null},{\"_index\":\"sales_csv\",\"_source\":{\"Order Date\":\"2016-01-29T18:35:00.000Z\"},\"sort\":[1576653361740],\"_score\":null},{\"_index\":\"sales_csv\",\"_source\":{\"Order Date\":\"2016-01-30T18:41:00.000Z\"},\"sort\":[1576653361739],\"_score\":null},{\"_index\":\"sales_csv\",\"_source\":{\"Order Date\":\"2016-01-30T18:41:00.000Z\"},\"sort\":[1576653361739],\"_score\":null},{\"_index\":\"sales_csv\",\"_source\":{\"Order Date\":\"2016-01-28T18:37:00.000Z\"},\"sort\":[1576653361740],\"_score\":null}]");
```

After conversion:

```
[
{"_index":"sales_csv","_source":{"Order Date":"2016-01-28T18:37:00.000Z"},"sort":[1576653361740],"_score":null},
{"_index":"sales_csv","_source":{"Order Date":"2016-01-29T18:35:00.000Z"},"sort":[1576653361740],"_score":null},
{"_index":"sales_csv","_source":{"Order Date":"2016-01-30T18:41:00.000Z"},"sort":[1576653361739],"_score":null},
{"_index":"sales_csv","_source":{"Order Date":"2016-01-30T18:41:00.000Z"},"sort":[1576653361739],"_score":null},
{"_index":"sales_csv","_source":{"Order Date":"2016-01-28T18:37:00.000Z"},"sort":[1576653361740],"_score":null}
]
```

I want to remove duplicates from the JSONArray.

Required output:

```
[
{"_index":"sales_csv","_source":{"Order Date":"2016-01-28T18:37:00.000Z"},"sort":[1576653361740],"_score":null},
{"_index":"sales_csv","_source":{"Order Date":"2016-01-29T18:35:00.000Z"},"sort":[1576653361740],"_score":null},
{"_index":"sales_csv","_source":{"Order Date":"2016-01-30T18:41:00.000Z"},"sort":[1576653361739],"_score":null}
]
```

Comment: What library are you using for json parsing? What is the full class name of JSONArray?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure exactly lib you are using JSONArray but it should be relatively straightforward to collect unique values from it.

This example shows using Jackson to read the JSON into a JsonNode, if you simply want to check equality based on the toString of each line you can create a HashSet of the values to filter the duplicates out.

```
final String json
        = "[{\"_index\":\"sales_csv\",\"_source\":{\"Order Date\":\"2016-01-28T18:37:00.000Z\"},\"sort\":[1576653361740],\"_score\":null},{\"_index\":\"sales_csv\",\"_source\":{\"Order Date\":\"2016-01-29T18:35:00.000Z\"},\"sort\":[1576653361740],\"_score\":null},{\"_index\":\"sales_csv\",\"_source\":{\"Order Date\":\"2016-01-30T18:41:00.000Z\"},\"sort\":[1576653361739],\"_score\":null},{\"_index\":\"sales_csv\",\"_source\":{\"Order Date\":\"2016-01-30T18:41:00.000Z\"},\"sort\":[1576653361739],\"_score\":null},{\"_index\":\"sales_csv\",\"_source\":{\"Order Date\":\"2016-01-28T18:37:00.000Z\"},\"sort\":[1576653361740],\"_score\":null}]";

final Set<String> result = new HashSet<>();
final com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode jsonNode
        = new com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper()
            .readValue(json, com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode.class);
jsonNode.forEach(t -> {
        result.add(t.toString());
    });
result.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 2):

How about using the Set of the collection framework?
The Set can check duplication data.

Sorry, my code looks bad but I believe you can understand my code.

```
package stackoverflow.test;

import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Test1 {

    public static JSONArray sampleJSONArrayData;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        try {
            sampleJSONArrayData = (JSONArray)parser.parse("[\n" +
                    "{\"_index\":\"sales_csv\",\"_source\":{\"Order Date\":\"2016-01-28T18:37:00.000Z\"}," +
                    "\"sort\":[1576653361740],\"_score\":null},\n" +
                    "{\"_index\":\"sales_csv\",\"_source\":{\"Order Date\":\"2016-01-29T18:35:00.000Z\"}," +
                    "\"sort\":[1576653361740],\"_score\":null},\n" +
                    "{\"_index\":\"sales_csv\",\"_source\":{\"Order Date\":\"2016-01-30T18:41:00.000Z\"}," +
                    "\"sort\":[1576653361739],\"_score\":null},\n" +
                    "{\"_index\":\"sales_csv\",\"_source\":{\"Order Date\":\"2016-01-30T18:41:00.000Z\"}," +
                    "\"sort\":[1576653361739],\"_score\":null},\n" +
                    "{\"_index\":\"sales_csv\",\"_source\":{\"Order Date\":\"2016-01-28T18:37:00.000Z\"}," +
                    "\"sort\":[1576653361740],\"_score\":null}\n" +
                    "]");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.print("Print original data : ");
        System.out.println(sampleJSONArrayData);

        Set<JSONObject> filterSetData = new HashSet();
        filterSetData.addAll(sampleJSONArrayData);

        System.out.print("Print filtered data : ");
        System.out.println(filteredJSONArray);
    }
}
```

This is the output

```
Print original data : [{"_index":"sales_csv","_source":{"Order Date":"2016-01-28T18:37:00.000Z"},"sort":[1576653361740],"_score":null},{"_index":"sales_csv","_source":{"Order Date":"2016-01-29T18:35:00.000Z"},"sort":[1576653361740],"_score":null},{"_index":"sales_csv","_source":{"Order Date":"2016-01-30T18:41:00.000Z"},"sort":[1576653361739],"_score":null},{"_index":"sales_csv","_source":{"Order Date":"2016-01-30T18:41:00.000Z"},"sort":[1576653361739],"_score":null},{"_index":"sales_csv","_source":{"Order Date":"2016-01-28T18:37:00.000Z"},"sort":[1576653361740],"_score":null}]
Print filtered data : [[{"_index":"sales_csv","_source":{"Order Date":"2016-01-28T18:37:00.000Z"},"sort":[1576653361740],"_score":null}, {"_index":"sales_csv","_source":{"Order Date":"2016-01-29T18:35:00.000Z"},"sort":[1576653361740],"_score":null}, {"_index":"sales_csv","_source":{"Order Date":"2016-01-30T18:41:00.000Z"},"sort":[1576653361739],"_score":null}]]
```

Comment: Will this approach work even if order of keys is different?

Comment: yes will be. Because the parser(JSONParser) rearrange the JSONObject data. so if order of keys is different, it will work.

Comment: you might want to handle `filteredJSONArray.add(filterSetData);` as it is creating an array of array as evident in the `Print filtered data : [[{"_index":"...`. Replacing it with ``filteredJSONArray.addAll(filterSetData);`` should work.

Comment: thanks! I didn't check it. so I change my code ```System.out.println(filterSetData);``` so it print just like that. ```Print filtered data : [{"_index":"sales_csv ... ```

Comment: You can also use `addAll` method as in `filteredJSONArray.addAll(filterSetData);` to add all elements of a collection to `JSONArray`.

Comment: I will study ```addAll()``` and will update code too. :)

Answer (score -1):

Use Set with String key, just put everything into, then get.